# Laravel redirect when not logged in

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

When a user tried to access a page they need to be logged in for I would like it to send them to the login page but with a message too.

I have:

```
Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    if (Auth::guest())
    {
        if (Request::ajax())
        {
            return Response::make('Unauthorized', 401);
        }
        else
        {
            return Redirect::guest('start')->withErrors('Please login to access that page.');
        }
    }
});
```

But my message bag is empty.

How can I do this?

Comment: store it in a session variable and remove it from the sessionvariable after you are done with it

Comment: Ok thanks, flash is what I want I guess.

Comment: How are you accessing it? Using the withVariable already stores it in the session...

Answer (score 0):

I think I can help you.

In your controller you can have:

```
return Redirect::route('Your route here)->with('message', 'Your message here');
```

And to show the message in your view:

```
@if (Session::has('message'))
        <div id="message">{{ Session::get('message') }}</div>
@endif
```